# Colocar data da postagem em portugues usando [processwire]

Tags: php, processwire

Eu estou a usar o processwire e para colocar a data da criação do poste usei o seguinte código

```
<?php  echo ( date("F j, Y ", $page->created). "at " . date("g:i A", $page->created));  ?></p>
```

No entanto este código faz mostrar a data no formato inglês e eu gostaria de traduzir para portugues

Vou mostrar a alteração que fiz

```
<p><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></span> Posted on <?php  echo ( date("F j, Y ", $page->created). "at " . date("g:i A", $page->created));  //antes
                                        //Alteração apartir daqui
                                      // strftime("%A, %d de %B de %Y", strtotime( $page->created));
                                        $en = ['','January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'];
                                        $pt = [' de ', 'janeiro', 'fevereiro', 'março', 'abril', 'maio', 'junho', 'julho', 'agosto', 'setembro', 'outubro', 'novembro', 'dezembro']; 
                                            echo("<br>");
                                         echo str_replace($en, $pt, strftime("%d de %B de %Y as %H:%M", strtotime($date)));
                                        ?>
</p>
```

O que estava antes  September 2, 2015 at 10:31 AM

Depois da alteração 01 de janeiro de 1970 as 01:00

As datas são diferentes

Se alguem puder adicione a tag processwire no stackoverflow ingles já existe criada

Comment: Então vc não pode mudar o locale?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

De acordo com [esta discussão](https://processwire.com/talk/topic/616-problem-displaying-a-datetime-field-in-spanish/), você pode fazer da seguinte forma definindo a linguagem no seu config.php:

```
$config->timezone = 'America/Sao_Paulo';
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'pt_BR');
```

E exibir a data da seguinte forma:

```
echo strftime("%A, %d de %B de %Y", strtotime( $page->created));
```

Caso não possa alterar a linguagem padrão, você pode traduzir manualmente:

```
    $date = '1441186272'; // $page->created

    $en = array('','January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December');
    $pt = array(' de ', 'janeiro', 'fevereiro', 'março', 'abril', 'maio', 'junho', 'julho', 'agosto', 'setembro', 'outubro', 'novembro', 'dezembro'); 

    echo str_replace($en, $pt, strftime("%d de %B de %Y as %H:%M", $date));
```

Retornará:

> 28 de Setembro de 2015 as 08:54

Comment: Defenir a Linguagem afectaria todo o template e eu pertendo que que apenas traduza quando primo o botão que criei "PT" então eu fiz uma variável que substituiria  consoante o botão que foi primido

Comment: ´$config->timezone = 'America/Sao_Paulo';
           setlocale(LC_ALL, 'pt_BR');
           echo strftime("%A, %d de %B de %Y", strtotime( $page->created));´

apos colocar o codigo o que foi exibido foi 

antes
September 2, 2015 at 10:31 AM

depois
Thursday, 01 de January de 1970

Comment: Formatei a resposta com mais uma alternativa para que tu possas utilizar sem alterar a linguagem padrão.

Comment: Returnou o seguinte:

 Posted on September 2, 2015 at 10:31 AM

Thursday, 01 de January de 1970

A data não cuicide e não traduziu na totalidade

Comment: Como fizestes??

Comment: editei lá em cima @Marcelo de Andrade

Comment: Você está dando um return, editei meu código. Troque o "return" por um "echo".

Comment: Mostrei lá em cima como ficou.

Comment: Retirei da resposta a função strtotime, o seu campo já deve ser do tipo date/datetime. Ficando da seguinte forma: `echo str_replace($en, $pt, strftime("%d de %B de %Y as %H:%M", $date));`

Comment: retorna o mesmo sem a função

Comment: Alguma ideia como solucionar isto ?

Comment: Qual retorno você tem ao dar um echo em `$page->created` ?

Comment: retorna '1441186272' parece  o tempo em segundos ou assim

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/29712/discussion-between-marcelo-de-andrade-and-amadeu-antunes).